# From Ruby to Python - Is there an equivalent of "try"?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In Ruby (on Rails, actually), I have the `try` function:

```
[].try(:[], 1) # => nil
[10].try(:[], 1) # => nil
[10, 20].try(:[], 1) # => 20
[10, 20, 30].try(:[], 1) # => 20

{}.try(:foo) # => nil
{ foo: 'bar' }.try(:foo) # => 'bar'
```

The function basically is a shortcut to avoid `if`s to check if the position is present.
Is there something similar in Python?

Comment: It looks like you're slightly misunderstanding the purpose of `try` in Rails. Array lookup for an invalid index in Ruby returns `nil` rather than raising an exception so doesn't require `try` in itself `[10][1] #=> nil`. The try comes in to avoid an error calling a method on a `nil` result e.g. `[10][1] + 3 # => NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass` but `[10][1].try(:+, 3) # => nil` (no exception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### **Dictionaries: `dict.get`**

You can use `dict.get`:

```
d = {'foo' : 'bar'}

print(d.get('foo'))
'bar'

print(d.get('xxxxx'))
None
```

You can also pass a default parameter to `get`:

```
print(d.get('xxxxx', 'Invalid Key!'))
Invalid Key!
```

The default value is printed out when the key does not exist in the dictionary.

---

#### **Lists: custom `try`-`except` block**

Unfortunately, lists do not have a `dict.get` equivalent in their API, so you'll need to implement one yourself. Thankfully, you can extend the `list` class and override `__getitem__` to do this cleanly.

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, idx, default='oops'):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(idx)
        except IndexError:
            return default

l = MyList([10, 20])

l[1]
# 20

l[3]
# 'oops'
```

Comment: what about `list` if i correct understand OP he also need such way for `list` type

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to have a method like `try` in Python, since `try` crucially relies on monkey patching `Object` and `NilClass`, and their Python equivalents (`object` and `NoneType`) cannot be monkey patched:

```
def try_object(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
    return getattr(self, f)(*args, **kwargs)

def try_none(self, f, *args, **kwargs):
    return None

object.try   = try_object
object.try   = try_object
#            ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax

NoneType.try = try_none
#            ^
# SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, you can write a global `try` function that behaves similar:

```
def tryy(obj, f, *args, **kwargs):
    if obj is None:
        return None
    else:
        return getattr(obj, f)(*args, **kwargs)

tryy([10, 20], '__getitem__', 1)
# >>> 20

tryy(None, '__getitem__', 1)
# >>> None
```

Answer (score 2):

python list object has no safe .get like dictionary has.

you will need to catch that with your own try and except:

```
try:
    return your_list[index]
except IndexError:
    return default # could be -1 for example
```

Answer (score 1):

With dict's you can use `d.get('foo')` which returns nothing if the key doesn't exist. You also can specify a defualt value, `d.get('foo', 'bar')` in which case `bar` is returned if the key `foo` isn't in the dict.

With lists, there isn't such obvious way. You can define a simple function,

```
def check_item(list_obj, item):
    try:
        return list_obj[item]
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Which will return the value if it exists, and nothing if not. Then simply call it `value = check_item(list_item, item_to_look)`

---

More advanced option would be to subclass the `list` class, and override the `__getitem__` method a function with similar logic to the above. (It requires some additional modifications to handle `slice` objects, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

In python, you must live by this mantra "**It's easier to ask forgiveness than get permission**".

For a list however, you can write a check like this to make the list into a dict with having its indexes as keys.

```
>>>en = enumerate([10, 20])
>>>dct = dict(en)
>>>dct.get(2)
None
>>>dct.get(1)
20
```

Answer (score 0):

combining solutions

```
def safe_get(data, key):
    if isinstance(data, (list, set, tuple)):
        return dict(enumerate(data)).get(key)
    elif isinstance(data, dict):
        return (data).get(key)
    else:
        return None

print safe_get([], 1)
None
print safe_get([10], 1)
None
print safe_get([10, 20], 1)
20
print safe_get([10, 20, 30], 1)
20
print safe_get({}, 'foo')
None
print safe_get({ 'foo': 'bar' }, 'foo')
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getattr` which will do what `try` would do for properties/attributes but it won't work for methods which need to be called.

eg

```
getattr(getattr(foo, 'prop1', None), 'prop2', None)
```

this is the same as in ruby

```
foo.try(:prop1).try(:prop2)
```